# Talend copy directly from one workspace to another

Tags: java, linux, talend

I was using an old version of talend (V4.1.0M4) and I upgraded to the new milestone (4.2)

This destroyed my project. I can't even open it now.

Anyone know of a way to just copy the contexts and the jobs directly to a new workspace so that I don't loose all of my work???

Thanks

Comment: AntonioCS, can you accept one of these so the community knows which solution worked, Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happened to me a while back too, I forget which version though. I just copied the project folders from the workspace folder in the old version to the workspace folder in the new version, i had no problems running my jobs. I believe when talend loads the job it will check for component compatibility and tell you if it finds a problem.

Answer (score 4):

In TALEND ,Right clik on `job option -> import` items then `import item` window open. in select root directory u can give a path of your existing workspace from where you want to copy your whole workspace or also required existing jobs.